# Detect if a transclude content has been given for a angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive (a progressbar) which should have two possible states, one without any description and one with a label on the left side. 
It would be cool to simple use the transcluded content for this label.

Does anyone know how I can add a class to my directive depending whether a transclude content has been given or not?

So I want to add:

```
<div class="progress" ng-class="{withLabel: *CODE GOES HERE*}">
    <div class="label"><span ng-transclude></span>
    <div class="other">...</div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

After release of Angular v1.5 with multi-slot transclusion it's even simpler. For example you have used `component` instead of `directive` and don't have access to `link` or `compile` functions. Yet you have access to `$transclude` service. So you can check presence of content with 'official' method:

```js
app.component('myTransclude', {
  transclude: {
    'slot': '?transcludeSlot'
  },
  controller: function ($transclude) {
    this.transcludePresent = function() {
      return $transclude.isSlotFilled('slot');
    };
  }
})
```

with template like this:

```html
<div class="progress" ng-class="{'with-label': withLabel}">
    <div class="label"><span ng-transclude="slot"></span>
    <div class="other">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This works well when using the multi-slot feature. But what if I just use the `transclude: true` setting on the component and want to know if any content is provided?

Comment: Shouldn't ng-class be: `ng-class="{'with-label': transcludePresent}"` ?

Answer (score 22):

Based on @Ilan's solution, you can use this simple $transclude function to know if there is transcluded content or not.

```
$transclude(function(clone){
    if(clone.length){
        scope.hasTranscluded = true;
    }
});
```

Plnkr demonstrating this approach with ng-if to set default content if nothing to transclude: http://plnkr.co/hHr0aoSktqZYKoiFMzE6

Comment: This looks like the most straight forward and quickest way in a component.  Within the component controller, inject `$transclude` and then use this function when it runs before `$onInit()` is called.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ednJwiceWD5vS0orewKW?p=preview

You can find the transcluded element inside the linking function and check it's contents:

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('progressbar', function(){
  return {
    scope: {},
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: "progressbar.html",
    link: function(scope,elm){
      var transcluded = elm.find('span').contents();
      scope.withLabel = transcluded.length > 0; // true or false
    }
  }
})
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="progress" ng-class="{'with-label': withLabel}">
    <div class="label"><span ng-transclude></span>
    <div class="other">...</div>
</div>
```

---

You can also create your custom transclusion directive like so:

```
app.directive('myTransclude', function(){

  return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl, $transclude){
      $transclude(function(clone){

        // Do something with this:
        // if(clone.length > 0) ...

        elm.empty();
        elm.append(clone);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: llan, you have some code commented out, in what case can this be true?  clone.length > 0, I tested, it is always 1

Comment: you would have !clone.length if there is nothing to transclude (ie empty <progressbar></progressbar>)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the solution from @plong0 & @Ilan, this seems to work a bit better since it works with whitespace as well.

```
$transcludeFn(function(clonedElement) {
    scope.hasTranscludedContent = clonedElement.html().trim() === "";
});
```

where previously `<my-directive>  </my-directive>` would return that it has a `.length` of `1` since it contains a text node.  since the function passed into `$transcludeFn` returns a jQuery object of the contents of the transcluded content, we can just get the inner text, remove whitespace on the ends, and check to see if it's blank or not.

**Note that this only checks for text**, so including html elements without text will also be flagged as empty. Like this: `<my-directive> <span> </span> </my-directive>` - This worked for my needs though.