# use of ngTransclude in ngInclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include, angularjs-ng-transclude

I cannot use the `ng-transclude` directive inside of template. I get the following error:

> Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element:

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="item.html">
<div ng-transclude>
</div>
</script>


<div ng-include="'item.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` uses `element transclusion` rather than `content transclusion`, so this won't work.

```
describe('element transclusion', function() {

  it('should support basic element transclusion', function() {
    module(function() {
      directive('trans', function(log) {
        return {
          transclude: 'element',
          priority: 2,
          controller: function($transclude) { this.$transclude = $transclude; },
          compile: function(element, attrs, template) {
            log('compile: ' + angular.mock.dump(element));
            return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
              log('link');
              var cursor = element;
              template(scope.$new(), function(clone) {cursor.after(cursor = clone);});
              ctrl.$transclude(function(clone) {cursor.after(clone);});
            };
          }
        };
      });
    });
    inject(function(log, $rootScope, $compile) {
      element = $compile('<div><div high-log trans="text" log>{{$parent.$id}}-{{$id}};</div></div>')($rootScope);
      $rootScope.$apply();
      expect(log).toEqual('compile: <!-- trans: text -->; link; LOG; LOG; HIGH');
      expect(element.text()).toEqual('1-2;1-3;');
    });
  });
```

> When we specify the transclude: 'element' option we cannot use a template, so we cannot even specify where to put the transcluded element with the ng-transclude attribute.

Use a `decorator` to use `content transclusion` instead:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="transcludeExample">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="foo">
  </script>
  
  <script>
    function delegator($delegate)
     {
     /* Override transclude configuration */ 
     $delegate[0].transclude = true;
     
     return $delegate;
     }


    function provider($provide)
     {
     /* Deocrate ng-include with a proxy function */
     $provide.decorator('ngIncludeDirective', ["$delegate", delegator]);
     }

    /* Inject the provider and the delegator methods with services */
    provider['$inject'] = ['$provide'];
    delegator['$inject'] = ['$delegate'];

    /* Inject the module with the new provider */
    angular.module('transcludeExample', []);
    angular.module("transcludeExample").config(["$provide",provider]);
  </script>
  
<div>Non-transcluded ID: {{$id}}</div><div ng-include src="'foo'" data-foo="{{$id}}">Transcluded ID: {{$id}}<ng-transclude></div></div>
</body>
```

Content Transclusion is defined as such:

> allowing a directive to wrap arbitrary child content inside additional template HTML.

whereas Element Transclusion means that:

> the template we pass in to the directive will replace the element with `ng-transclude` directive.

**References**

- [AngularJS Source: compileSpec.js - Element Transclusion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/compileSpec.js#L7082)
- [AngularJS Source: compileSpec.js - Content Transclusion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/compileSpec.js#L5892)
- [AngularJS Hub: Transclusion](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/customdirectives/transclusion/)
- [Experiment: Decorating Directives](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/)
- [Decorating AngularJS Directives to Support Rx.Observable](https://barrysimpson.net/posts/rx-directive-decorators)
- [Design Patterns with AngularJS Directives](http://apparently.me.uk/angularjs-directive-patterns/)
- [AngularJS Issue #3759: Better error message with transclude / ng-transclude](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3759)
- [Hash URIs: The Deeper Questions](http://www.jenitennison.com/2011/03/06/hash-uris.html#the-deeper-questions)
- [A Guide To Transclusion in AngularJS](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html)
- [Transclusion will never Catch On](http://everypageispageone.com/2014/09/15/transclusion-will-never-catch-on/)
- [Transclusion in Angular - Matt Briggs](http://mattbriggs.net/blog/2014/01/22/transclusion-in-angular/)
- [Decorate Core Directives in Angular](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-hacking-core)
- [Detect if a transclude content has been given for a angularjs directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547781/)

Answer (score -1):

You should create a directive which renders item.html.
In the directive definition object add `transclude: true` property.

```
angular.module('MyModule')
  .directive('item', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope:{},
      transclude: true,
      templateUrl: 'item.html'
    };
  });



...


<item>
  <!-- here goes your transcluded content -->
</item>
```