# Replacing parts of directive template when their respective transclusion content is present

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to do the following:

If I add `<my-custom-directive></<my-custom-directive>`

it should expand to

```
<div class="my-custom-container">
   <label class="my-custom-label">Fallback</label>
   <input class="my-custom-input"/>
</div>
```

which can be done by setting the above as `template` and `replace:true` in DDO.

If I add the following in HTML:

```
<my-custom-directive>
   <my-custom-label class="users-custom-class"><span>Custom content</span><my-custom-label>
</<my-custom-directive>
```

it should expand to

```
<div class="my-custom-container">
   <label class="my-custom-label users-custom-class"><span>Custom content</span></label>
   <input class="my-custom-input"/>
</div>
```

Which means if the user wants to provide custom `<label>`, `<input>` etc, we use transclusion, and the transcluded content replaces respective slot in the original template, similar to how a `replace:true` directives's  would replace itself with it's template.

I'm not able to combine the `replace` and transclusion functionality.

---

What I've so far (*something-working-state*) is the following:

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .directive('transTest', function() {
    return {
      transclude: {
        lab: '?labelTest',
        inp: '?inputTest'
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<div class="container"><label ng-transclude="lab">Fallbacl label</label><input type="text" placeholder="fallback" ng-transclude="inp"></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
        console.log(transclude())
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div trans-test class="test">
    <label-test>test label</label-test>
    <input-test>test input</input-test>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the trancluded content goes inside the translude containing element, instead of replacing it. I've read the [source code comments](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L278), articles and also checked the implementation of [ui-bootstrap-accordion](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js) and tried my luck with `transclude:'element'`, but it leaves nothing in DOM but a comment.

transclusion, replace etc are the available options that I've found which offers functionality similar to what I'm trying to achieve. But they don't seem to play well toghether. What is the correct way to achieve this kind of  functionality in angular, if possible..?

Comment: It seems muli-slot `element` transclude not yet been supported. There has [#14244](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14244) talking similar behavior.

Comment: @Cotton that looks like the functionality I'm after... thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 5):

It seems I finally made it work. The solution is made of 2 parts:

1. Define directives for the transclude-slot elements with template similar to the fallback (default).

   The major reason for doing this is to make use of angular's built in capability to copy attributes to templates root element when `replace:true` is set in DDO. I didn't wanted to do it manually in the link function.
   Another reason is that it lets you add additional features such as transclusion which is not necessary in default template
2. The second step is to **not define** `ng-transclude` directive in the template, instead use the `transclude` function passed to `link` for accessing the trancluded content of various slots, and replace the respective element with the transcluded content if it is present (using `transclude.isSlotFilled()`)

Well, this wasn't easy to get my mind around, and it isn't easy to explain as well. Hope the demo below explains it better than words:

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .directive('transTest', function() {
    return {
      replace: true,
      transclude: {
        lab: '?labelTest',
        inp: '?inputTest'
      },
      template: '<div class="test-parent"><label class="fallback-label">Fallback </label><br><input type="text" class="fallback-input"></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
        if (transclude.isSlotFilled('lab')) {
          var label = transclude(angular.noop, null, 'lab');
          element.find('label').replaceWith(label);
        }
        if (transclude.isSlotFilled('inp')) {
          var input = transclude(angular.noop, null, 'inp');
          element.find('input').replaceWith(input);
        }
      }
    }
  }).directive('labelTest', function($compile) {
    return {
      template: '<label class="fallback-label ng-transclude">Fallback </label>',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true
    }
  }).directive('inputTest', function($compile) {
    return {
      template: '<input type="text" class="fallback-input">',
      replace: true
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div trans-test class="test">
    <label-test class="custom-label">Custom content</label-test>
    <input-test class="custom-input" placeholder="custom"></input-test>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <div trans-test class="test">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at angular-message. This is exactly what you're looking for. In terms of implementations it's a set of 2 directives : the container one, exposing a controller in order to register child. And the childs registering themselves in the container. So you can have a default implementation when a child is not present or have a child overriding the default.

Comment: @Walfrat Well I don't think so... Maybe you misunderstood the question... I have a huge template and I need to be able to replace specific parts of it if needed. ng-messages simply have one type on child which is ng-message element on which there is an `ng-if`... where does `ng-messages` use multislot transclusion..?

Comment: With the include part you can include a default template that you can override then. Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages section Reusing and Overriding Messages. I'm not saying that angular message is the solution, but the way it is implemented look like what you're looking for. Of course that's for the most generic way.

Comment: @Walfrat I didn't knew it had such an overriding feature, i'll look into the source, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for a more elegant solution, but you can tap into the  directive's controller `$transclude` function to [find out if a `transclusion-slot` has been filled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35348277/1245971).

```
controller: function($transclude, $scope) {
  $scope.fallback = !$transclude.isSlotFilled('lab');
```

Then, use that information to build your template.

```
template: '<div class="container">\
  <label ng-if="fallback === true">Fallback label</label>\
  <div ng-if="fallback === false" ng-transclude="lab"></div>\
```

However, if you can fully define the content being transcluded,

```
<label-test>
    <label>test label</label>
</label-test>
```

it might make more sense for the destination content to be replaced - rather than the entire element:

```
template: '<div class="container">\
  <div ng-transclude="lab">\
    <label>Fallback label</label>\
  </div>\
```

Here is a plunker showing both approaches: http://plnkr.co/edit/EEq5vovFrSW7kG81yWuf?p=preview

Comment: The problem with this is that there will be a useless `<div>` breaking the whole layout (of things like bootstrap components) which is what I'm trying to avoid by using `tranclude:element`, `replace:true` etc my problem statement was: *"not able to combine the replace and transclusion` functionality"*

Comment: What about <ng-transclude ng-transclude-slot="lab">, instead of <div ng-transclude="lab">.  Same problem?

Comment: I was [testing that](https://jsfiddle.net/wwsxorqa/) it leaves a useless `<ng-transclude` wrapper element in dom breaking the frameworks expectations I think this needs to be fixed in compile or something in source code level as mentioned in this [ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14244) :/

Comment: nice - i thought about suggesting that approach, but worried you might need to accept any type of input or label.  since you can guaranty the user will use label-test and input-test, it should work.

Comment: Anyway I'm giving you the bounty since the answer is a starting point, also if I don't  it'll go back to the emptynes it came from :v